# Edit Post Metadata in Divi Extra theme

Tags: wordpress, divi-theme

I am using Divi Extra theme for my website, using post view counter [post-views] plugin to display the total number of views for posts. By default, post views are displayed before/after the post content, would like to display the total number of views in the post metadata along with other info as below:

post create by | created date | number of comments | ratings | [post-views].

could you please point out the files to be changed to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the post templates from the Extra theme folder to a child theme and modify the post meta there. For example, if you want to modify normal posts, you would copy the single.php.